# stackexchange.redis wildcard delete

Tags: redis, wildcard, stackexchange.redis

We are using StackExhange.Redis and I need to do a delete on a partial key.

Our keys are structured like:

```
user_items_itemid
```

What I want to do is issue a delete command for user_item* and have it delete all of the keys that start with user_item.

Is there away to do this type of wildcard delete statement through StackExchange.Redis

Answer (score 1):

That kind of delete operation is not supported by Redis. What you can do is use the [SCAN](http://redis.io/commands/scan) command with the pattern you want, and then delete those keys. The best solution is to keep track of those keys in advance, for example by using a set. You may be tempted to use the [KEYS](http://redis.io/commands/keys) command, but it's not recommended for production environments.